# Entity Framework Core Database First Model Generate Tool Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having a "Class Library (.NET Core)" where I will put all my data access logic in it. I installed Entity Framework Core.

These are the following libraries that are installed :

> - "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2"
> - "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2"
> - "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2"
> - "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2"
> - "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1"

I use this command line snippet to generate all the database models

```
Scaffold-DbContext "data source=.;initial catalog=Burgeritso;integrated security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Everything generates fine however the code generated in the DbContext has so many unknown generated methods please find the attached screen shot:

[image: EF Generated Code]

the Methods are unlined in red at lines 15 , 23 , 31 , 47.

What could be possibly done wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: What is it telling you in the error window?

Comment: CS1061 C# 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and no extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found #are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?#